# Calendar UI listview as dayview

Tags: android, calendar

I have the lollipop version of calendar. In DayView,listview is zoomable like as
[image] [image]

How it is possible?

- What concept used in this listview expandable type.
- I thought it is pinchzoom but it's not.Any related tutorial to help identified what concept used it is

Comment: use expandablelistview

Comment: expandable listview with touchlisterner to used or not

Comment: any tutorial related this expndablelistview

Comment: refer  http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

Comment: i refer that it not exactly like expandable listview